# FMP 14 - Auto Populate a Field based on a calculation

Tags: filemaker

I am using FMP 14 and would like to auto-populate field `A` based on the following calulation:

```
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v1" ; "1st" ) or
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v2" ; "2nd" ) or
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v3" ; "3rd" ) or
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v4" ; "4th" ) or
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v5" ; "5th" ) or
If ( Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v6" ; "6th" )
```

The above code is supposed to auto-populate the value `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd` ... in field `A` depending on the name of the object the `Get (ActiveLayoutObjectName)` function returns.  I have named each of my tabs, but the calculation is only returning 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your calculation is written makes very little sense. Each one of the If() statements returns a result of either "1st", "2nd", etc. or nothing (an empty string). You are then applying `or` to all these results. Since only of them can be true, your calculation is essentially doing something like:

```
 "" or "2nd" or "" or "" or "" or ""
```

which happens to return 1 (true), but has no useful meaning.

You should be using the Case() function here:

```
Case ( 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v1" ; "1st" ; 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v2" ; "2nd" ; 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v3" ; "3rd" ; 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v4" ; "4th" ; 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v5" ; "5th" ; 
Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) = "tab_Visits_v6" ; "6th" 
)
```

Note also that a calculation field may not always refresh itself as a result of user switching a tab. This refers to an *unstored* calculation field; if you are trying to use this as the formula to be auto-entered into a "regular' (e.g. Text) field, it will *never* update.

---

### Added:

> Here is our situation. We see a patient a maximum of 6 times. We have
>   a tab for each one of those 6 visits.

I would suggest you use a *portal* to a *related* table of Visits instead of a tab control. A tab control is designed to display **fixed** components of user interface - not dynamic *data*. And certainly not data split into separate records. You should have only one unique record for each patient - and as many records for each patient's visits as may be necessary (potentially unlimited).

If you like, you can use the portal rows as buttons to select a specific visit to view in more detail (similar to a tab control, except that the portal shows the "tabs" as vertical rows). A one-row portal to the same Visits table, filtered by the user selection, would work very well for this purpose, I believe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. It sounds like my idea of using a calculation in a field may not work. Here is our situation. We see a patient a maximum of 6 times. We have a tab for each one of those 6 visits. On each tab, there is a field called visit #.  I was just trying to pre populate the visit number into the field on each of those tabs, so the user doesn't have to do it.  Is there a way to hard code the visit number into the field on each tab?  Each tab creates a new record in the table. 

Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: @Linda I don't think you are on the right track with this overall - see a more detailed response in the addition to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you Michael, for taking the time to answer my questions.  I have set up a relationship between my patient master table and my visits table.  The tab set up was requested by the user.  I'm new to fmp and didn't realize that a tabbed presentation might not be the best for what we are trying to do.  I'll have to give all of this some thought.  Thanks, Linda

Comment: @Linda "*The tab set up was requested by the user*" If the user insists, you could give them fake tabs: six buttons placed horizontally, with the aforementioned one-row filtered portal underneath. That way, although the user interface limits the choice to the first six visits, at least the underlying data structure is correct.

Comment: P.S. If you're new to Filemaker, I'd suggest you join one of the FM community forums, where questions like these are easier to debate in detail.

Comment: thank you for all your good ideas. I am new to Fmp so will find a good community forum.  Do you have one you would like to recommend?

Comment: I believe there are only 3 ATM: http://fmforums.com/, https://community.filemaker.com and http://www.filemakertoday.com/com/forum.php. I am most active at the first one, but do lurk around and make your own choice (or choices).

Answer (score 0):

With 1. .... it would be easy:

```
Right (Get ( ActiveLayoutObjectName ) ; 1) & "."
```

Thanks for pointing out, that my first version does not work.

Comment: "2th" or "3th" are not the expected results here.